# recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have seen the following problem in my regular study, which I am not able to solve. Please solve it for me.

Let $C_0,..., C_{k-1}$ be fixed integers and consider the recurrence relation of order $k$,
$X_{n+k} = C_{k-1} X_{n+k-1} + C_{k-2} X_{n+k-2} + \cdots + C_1 X_{n+1} + C_0 X_n$.
Show that once $k$ values of $X_m$ are specified, all values of $X_n$ are determined.

Let $f(r) = r^k - C_{k-1} r^{k-1} - \cdots - C_0$;
we call this characteristic equation (polynomial)  of the recurrence relation. Show that 
if $f(p) = 0$ then $X_n = cp^n$ satisfies the recurrence relation for any $c$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}$ (complex member)

Thanks in very advance...
mahima

Comment: Try working with small values of n, and then try induction for a general proof.

Comment: You have posted several low-quality questions without accepting any answers on them. In addition, "please solve it for me" is not really in the spirit of this site: you should be here to _learn_, not just to copy answers. Think about what you don't understand, and ask about that instead.

Comment: Please format more clearly using $\LaTeX$.  Then please do not assign homework-the imperative mode is offensive.  Can you see why if you have $k$ values you have the rest?  Then plug in the suggestion and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

**First Question**

In general, it is *not true* that once $k$ values of $X_n$ are specified, all values of $X_n$ are determined. Here is a simple counterexample.  There are many others.

Consider the recurrence
$$X_{n+2}=0\cdot X_{n+1} +2X_n.$$
So, in the notation of the question, $k=2$. Let us specify that $X_0=2$ and $X_2=4$.  This says absolutely nothing about $X_n$ when $n$ is odd.

Since what we were asked to prove is not true, let's try to prove something *near* what is asked for.  To make typing easier, and so that all the symbols won't get in the way of the ideas, I will mostly use a concrete example.

Look for example at
$$X_{n+3}=3X_{n+2}+5X_{n+1}+7X_n.\qquad\text{(Equation $1$)}$$ 
and suppose that we know $X_m$ for three different values of $m$.

Note that if we knew $X_0$, $X_1$, and $X_2$, the *first three values*, then we could use Equation $1$ to calculate, one after the other, $X_n$ for all $n$.

So now suppose we know three values, but they are, say, $X_5$, $X_{22}$, and $X_{100}$.

Here is how we proceed, in principle.

The first three values are unknown.  Call them $x$, $y$, and $z$.  Use the recurrence to calculate the $X_n$, one after the other.  Of course our answers will be in terms of the unknown $x$, $y$, and $z$.  But the important thing to notice is that each $X_n$ is a simple *linear combination* of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

So a certain linear combination of $x$, $y$, and $z$, namely the one that gives $X_5$, has a known value.  You should work out this linear combination, it can be done in two steps.

Similarly, one can in principle work out the linear combination that gives $X_{22}$, and the one that gives $X_{100}$.  Now we have $3$ linear equations in the $3$ unknowns $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Solve these equations.  Here we bump into a problem.  Everything is OK if the matrix for the equations is *invertible*.  However, it need not be, and then 
$(x, y, z)$ is not determined by $(X_5, X_{22}, X_{100})$.

However, "most of the time" the matrix will be invertible, and we will be OK.
I could introduce more theory here, and mention **Vandermonde determinants** and their close relatives, but I doubt that you are expected to go that deep.

**Consecutive values:** If we know $X_m$ for $k$ *consecutive values* of $m$, then everything is determined.  Suppose, for example, for our Equation $1$, we know $(X_{100}, X_{101}, X_{102})$.  Then we can use Equation $1$ to calculate "forward", and find $X_{103}$, $X_{104}$, and so on.

But notice we can also work our way "backwards."  Suppose we want $X_{99}$. Then using the fact that
$$X_{102}=3X_{101}+ 5X_{100}+7X_{99}$$
we can solve the above equation of $X_{99}$, then do something similar to find $X_{98}$, and so on.  We conclude that if $3$ consecutive values are known, everything is known.

The same idea works for general $k$.  Maybe the question meant to say $k$ *consecutive* values, and the consecutive bit got left out!

**Second Question**: This one is straightforward. We want to show that putting $X_j=cp^j$ (for all $j$) "works."

Substitute $cp^j$ for $X_j$ in each side of the recurrence. We want to show that the two sides turn out to be the same: That's what it means for $X_j=cp^j$ to be a solution.

The left-hand side is 
$$cp^{n+k} \qquad \text{(Left Side)}$$
The right-hand side is messier. We get
$$C_{k-1}cp^{n+k-1}+C_{k-2}cp^{n+k-2}+\cdots + C_0cp^n \qquad\text{(Right side)}$$

We want to show that the two displayed quantities  are equal.  Their difference is
$$cp^{n+k}-C_{k-1}cp^{n+k-1}-C_{k-2}cp^{n+k-2}-\cdots - C_0cp^n$$
which is equal to 
$$cp^n\left(p^k -C_{k-1}p^{k-1}-C_{k-2}p^{k-2}-\cdots -C_0\right)$$
But the above expression is simply $cp^nf(p)$, which is $0$ since $p$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial.